# Whatis the difference between a 32bit program on a 32bit OS and 32bit program on a 64bit OS?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

In my computer its running 32bit OS on the 64bit processor. So all the application installed are 32bit and my computer having a 2GB RAM. If I install a 64bit OS while keeping the same 32bit applications, will this improve the performance?? Or is there any disadvantage?

Comment: This is not a coding question ... But: If your Computer has only 2 GB RAM, you definitly will have no benefit from using a 64bit Windows ...

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Unless it is useful with the larger register file in case of x86/x86_64.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Indeed, one can run the CPU in 64bits mode and use 32bits addresses as in [the x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

Comment: @diapir: That was not the question: The OP asked, if he has benefits when he uses 32 bit software on a 64 bit os with ONLY 2GB ram. The answer: No benefits.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer I was elaborating on the random_user comment about a larger register file on x64 (16 registers vs 8), pointing that x64 code can run faster and sticking to a 32bits address space can raise performance further. So the actual answer is **it depends** and in the case of a computer with just 2Go of RAM, there's a good chance performance would worsen due to swapping. But again, it depends on usage.

Comment: What about the gaming performance?

Answer (score 2):

Talking about 32-bit and 64-bit software means that such software was developed in order to take advantage of CPUs with 32-bit or 64-bit registers size.

Registers are tiny portions of memory (NOT the RAM) used directly by a processing unit to temporarily save operations results (kind of variables), e.g. when summing two numbers the ALU reads from two registers, performs the operation and writes the answer in another register. The bigger those registers, the bigger values it can handle. A 32-bit processor has registers than can handle values up to 32 bits of size, as well as 64-bit processors can deal with numbers of a double size than 32-bit-based processors, which 
results in 2^32 more values.

A 32-bit OS is an OS than works performing CPU operations on a machine with 32-bit CPU registers; a 64-bit OS works fine on 64-bit processors, but not on 32-bit ones because their registers are too small for such OS.

As a program runs on an OS, 32-bit apps will run (well, most times they do) on a 64-bit OS albeit they will use only half of any CPU register they need, simply because the program was designed not to deal with values bigger than 2^32 bit: this means that a 32-bit app running on a 64-bit OS will run without getting any particular performance improvement. As well, a 64-bit app will never run on a 32-bit OS because it needs more resources than those actually available.

Hope I was clear and correct enough, I studied processor architectures years ago...

Answer (score 1):

This applies for a 64-bit app on x86/x86_64:

- The 64-bit system will consume more RAM and most importantly cache because the larger pointers. This may be a performance bottleneck in case there are lots of pointers.
- The 64-bit system will give you twice as many registers, twice as large. This makes it possible to store more variables in registers, which will be a performance gain.

So the choice may depend on which application you decide to benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

The point of 64 bit is that apps can use more than 2gb of  virtual memory. If you have more than 4gb of ram and your apps need to use more than 2gb of memory (sql server!) then potentially there will be a performance memory (because it can store more pages in memory rather than reading them from disk)

If this isn't the case and you have the same amount of memory then you won't get a performance increase and possibly a slight decrease as (assuming you are on windows here) to handle 32 bit apps working on a 64 bit o/s there is a complex system of redirections that happen (app asks for system32 and is sent to syswow64) - some of these are simple but some like the com registration lookups can cause many reg opens under the hood (do a regopen for a clsid that doesn't exists and see how many kernel32 makes on your behalf using procmon!).

So unless you have a very specific use case, which it sounds like you don't, it won't be faster